# How can i declare function (not method) with ruby on rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, function

I give you an function exemple:

```
def debug(var)
    raise var.inspect
end
```

in PHP its simple, I put

```
function debug($var)
{
    var_dump($var);
}
```

and I just have to include the file where is define this function and it is aviable in all my code where and when I want.

How can I do the same in rails app? I want a function, not a method in class and i want to be able to call it evrywhere in my code.

Comment: Can you tell us why you're stressing on "function, not a method..."?  How are they different?

Comment: Why do you want such thing? Even in modern PHP applications for these are used methods, but from static classes, i.e. `App::debug($var)` available in all your scope via autoloader

Answer (score 1):

You can define the method in a module, and then include the module wherever you need access to the method, as follows:

```
module SomeModule
  def debug(var)
    raise var.inspect
  end
end
```

And then in another class:

```
class SomeClass
  include SomeModule

  def some_method
    debug(self)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's bad design to add global functions, btw they wont be functions: if you attach something to the global namespace, it will still be a method: remember in Ruby everything is an object.

Attach it to a module.

Example:

```
module Utils

  def self.debug(var)  
    raise var.inspect
  end
end
```

And use it wherever needed:

```
Utils.debug(something)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by saying that what you show as a function in first example is a method.

In Ruby everything is an object. So if you define some method just like in your first example, it still belongs to some object.

```
irb(main):001:0> self
=> main
irb(main):002:0> self.class
=> Object
```

You see, even if you just call `irb`, the context you execute code is an instance of `Object` class.

So what you actually want is a method which is available globally in scope of Rails application. You can achieve it by including some module right in your application (like in other answers to this question)

However, I suggest different way. Instead of creating a global method, create a class/module with that method. Classes and modules are globally accessible, so you will be able to use it everywhere (see fivedigit's answer for example).

Answer (score 0):

There are no functions in Ruby, what you want is not possible.